# Does "int a = int();" necessarily give me a zero?

Tags: c++

Does `int a = int();` necessarily give me a zero?

How about if `int` is replaced by `char`, `double`, `bool` or pointer type?

Where is this specified in the language standard, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do built-in types have default constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **Does `int a = int();` necessarily give me a zero?**

Yes, the standard guarantees that it gives you zero.
This is known as **Value Initialization**. For the type `int`, **Value Initialization** basically ends up being an **Zero Initialization**.

> **Where is this specified in the language standard, please?**

The rules are clearly specified in the standard in **section 8.5**. 
I will quote the relevant ones to the Q here:

**C++03: 8.5 Initializers**
**Para 7:**

> **An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.**

Value Initialization & Zero Initialization are defined in **8.5 Para 5** as:

> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default 
>     constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible 
>     default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static 
>     data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**
>
> To **zero-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> — **if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T**;
>   — if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject
>     is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

Note: The bold texts are emphasized by me.

Comment: And there's another paragraph somewhere where it spells out that value initialization for `int` means initialize to `0`...

Comment: @juanchopanza: If you follow the bold text in the standard quotes above, You will see how it comes to that.

Comment: I know that, the text wasn't there when I wrote the comment. I recently went through this in c++11 trying to figure out `{}` initialization :)

Comment: @AlokSave: What you think about constructors of built in types? int() looks like a constructor call & Bjarne Stroustrup in his book The C++ programming language says that built in types have also constructors. Visit & read this: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=15 and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-default-constructor-built-in-types/

Comment: @AlokSave: Please read the sections 10.4.2 & 6.2.8 of The C++ Programming Language by Stroustrup.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, any built-in type is always initialized to zero when default-initialized. Keep in mind that in most scenarios a built-in type is **not** default initialized so this won't necessarily print out `0`:

```
int i;
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Comment: Value of uninitialized built in type as in the example is indeterminate and accessing is undefined behaviour(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)