# what does char() print out in C++

Tags: c++, null, char

I tried to find documentation on this but there doesn't seem to be any definite answers to this. I tried in an example program, and it seems to `\0` but is this reliable behavior? What does char() initialize to and is this in the C++ standard.

```
int main()
{
  std::cout<<char()<<std::endl;

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `char()` doesn't print anything. It creates a value-initialized (e.g. zero-initialized in this case) `char` temporary. What you do with it thereafter is up to you.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you want to know the behaviour of.  _"what does char() print out"_ is kinda loosey-goosey language.  Specific code is best in this case to define what you mean.

Comment: I've added a simple program. @WhozCraig do you mean the numerical `0`? When I run the program I provided it is a blank.

Comment: That's the overload for `char` kicking in for that `operator <<` (which basically does nada on a nullchar, which is what you have).  It is still be called, however. You can [see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/j943hGTeY) if you check the disassembly calls.

Comment: @TWhite read about [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) and [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). `char()` is similar to `int()` or `long()` and produce the same value in the specified types. [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113365/995714), [Does "int a = int();" necessarily give me a zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10100776/995714), [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113365/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `char()` returns `\0` is normal, and it's reliable (integer variables are initialized to 0 with such a syntax, and pointers are initialized to `nullptr`). For example, `unsigned short int()` will also returns 0. For a `char`, it's obviously not the character "0", but the `NUL` character.

Then, when trying to print that, you're trying to print a `char` that is used, in `char*` strings, to mark the end of the string... So without surprise, it isn't printed at all, even as a single character.

Comment: *Isn't printed at all* is not correct. The NUL character is printed with the shown statement. It may be the case that the terminal does not show anything. But if you redirect the output to a file, you will notice that there is one byte in the file and that byte has the value zero.

Comment: @j6t We're not in the case of writing to a binary file, but to the _CONSOLE_... Which is particular, as you know it - for example, writing a TAB on a binary file is only the character 9, but on a console, it's (usually) between 1 and 8 spaces...