# Initialize integer literal to std::size_t

Tags: c++

There are known ways to manipulate the type of an integer literal

```
0L;  // long
3U;  // unsigned integer
1LL; // long long
```

What I need is a way to initialize an integer literal to `std::size_t`. I supposed that doing

```
2U; // unsigned int
```

would be enough, but I still get a compiler error when calling a function template that expects two arguments of the same integral type (no matching function to call for `func(unsigned int, size_t`)

I know/verified that explicitly casting ( `static_cast<std::size_t>(1)` ) the first argument solves the problem but I'm asking if there's a prettier solution

**EDIT**

the function has a signature

```
template <class T> const T& func(const T& a, const T& b);
```

**EDIT2**

I don't know if this question is to "blame" but I'm happy to announce that [this is upcoming](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4254.html) (cudos @malat for mentioning this in the comments)

Comment: How do you call `func`? Can you show your code?

Comment: Please show both the call and the declaration of the function you want to call. Also please show the *complete* and *unedited* error log. And *edit your question* to include that information.

Comment: @dalle That would be unportable to C, where `'0'` has type `int`.

Comment: This is [upcoming](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4254.html)

Comment: @malat: What is the state of the proposal? Which language version will it appear?

Comment: @Silicomancer: According to the Revision History [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0330r5.html), the last update was that it's being targeted for C++23 (as of June 17th, 2019).

Comment: Sad truth is, that `size_t` was somehow forgotten when someone defined the header `<cinttypes>`. Had it not been forgotten, I muse, this would be the place for some `SIZE_C()` macro in the spirit of the others defined there, such as `UINT8_C()`. `UINTMAX_C()` comes closest to it as `size_t` is defined to be able to hold the biggest available integer type.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is no such standard facility. C99 and C++11 implementations do have such macros in `<stdint.h>`/`<cstdint>`. But even there, the macros are only defined for the `stdint.h` types, which do not include `size_t`.

You [could](http://ideone.com/iuktBB) define a user-defined literal operator:

```
constexpr std::size_t operator "" _z ( unsigned long long n )
    { return n; }

auto sz = 5_z;
static_assert( std::is_same< decltype( sz ), std::size_t >::value, "" );
```

The `constexpr` is necessary to use it in array bounds `int arr[ 23_z ]` or `case 9_z:` labels.

Most would probably consider the lack of macros to be an advantage :) .

---

Cuteness aside, the best way is to use brace initialization: `std::size_t{ 42 }`. This is not equivalent to `std::size_t( 42 )` which is like a nasty C cast — presumably what you were avoiding with `static_cast`. Quite the opposite: the braces require that the value inside is exactly representable in the targeted type. So, `char{ 300 }` and `std::size_t{ -1 }` are both ill-formed.

Braces and parens look similar, but they're polar opposites in safety when initializing temporaries. Braces are safer than the literal operator could ever be, since unlike a function they can discriminate compile-time values.

Comment: This solution would be unportable to C... ;)

Comment: @dalle Less trickily so, though. Of course, your method could be made portable simply by having a global `char c;` and doing `5 * sizeof(c)`; amenable to macros for those so inclined.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Both answers got +1 but this is chosen for additionally using `constexpr`

Comment: +1 you should propose this for library inclusion using `z` instead of `_z`. It would simplify things like `for (auto i = 0z; i < v.size(); ++i)`

Comment: @TemplateRex It's been informally proposed on the std-discussion list/Google group. There was not much support for the idea. Personally I think this is part of the "almost" in "almost always auto."

Comment: [The aforementioned std-proposals discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/tGoPjUeHlKo) if anybody wants to read it.

Comment: Is there any way to use this with with a `#define` statement.  E.g., I have `#define BLOCKSIZE 262144`.  `BLOCKSIZE_z` doesn't work.

Comment: @thc You can use the `##` operator of the preprocessor to append `_z` after substituting `BLOCKSIZE`, but that can only be done inside a macro. At that point you might as well just cast.

Comment: I would disagree on std::size_t( 42 ) being a C-cast. (std::size_t)42 is the cast syntax. std::size_t( 42 ) is just a ctor call. the same as being used for members in ctor initializer lists for example ( before uniform initialization came along this was the only option )

Comment: @QBziZ An initializer list uses {} and a ctor call uses (). These are two different things. The values in either of these two things undergo only implicit conversions. The constructor-like syntax `size_t(value)` denotes explicit conversions so it’s a third different thing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I do not disagree with what you say. My point is that A::A() : somemember( 5 ) {...} implies a ctor call for somemember. somemember could be size_t. this indeed converts, and thus can be seen as a conversion ctor, not a cast.

Comment: @QBziZ That is not how the standard uses the term “constructor” and especially not “conversion constructor.”

Comment: @Potatoswatter that is true as well, ctors are not defined for built-in types. but the ctor syntax does apply to them and the results are the same. there is even a default ctor for them. all of this is done explicitly to leverage generic programming for built-in types. so formally size_t(5) is not a ctor, but it would do the community well to not consider them as ugly C-casts.

Comment: @QBziZ [citation needed]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors. The comments are where a lot of info resides as well. And indeed, not according the C++ Standard but I do interpret this grey zone in a pragmatic manner.

Comment: @QBziZ Okay, that page supports your argument if you ignore the answers and read the comments instead. Except I just read the comments and they still don't support or mention the idea that default-initialization of a scalar type involves a constructor, which is what you've asserted here.

Comment: "Braces are safer than the literal operator could ever be, since unlike a function they can discriminate compile-time values."  We can use a `<char...>` literal operator.  That would be a lot of work, but it is technically possible (except for the most negative value, in which case the `-` cannot be parsed by the literal operator).

Answer (score 49):

Starting from C++23 you can use the `uz` or `UZ` literal for `size_t`.

```
auto size = 42uz;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(size), std::size_t>);
```

Paper: [P0330R8](https://wg21.link/P0330R8)
cppreference: [Integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Answer (score 35):

There is no dedicated suffix for `std::size_t`. In C++11, you could create a user-defined literal for it, though:

```
std::size_t operator "" _sz (unsigned long long int x)
{
  return x;
}

// Usage:

auto s = 1024_sz;

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(s), std::size_t>::value, "He's wrong");
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/VBiyBB)

Comment: +1 for showing a decent usage of what is arguably the least-used operator in the language.

Comment: +1 but I'd prefer `z` instead of `sz` to conform to the `%z` for C99 printf

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the function, you may also be able to do this and may find it cleaner:

```
auto result = func<size_t>(1, some_var);
```

For example, I've done this with `std::max`:

```
auto result = std::max<size_t>(0, std::min<size_t>(index, vec.size()-1));
```

By explicitly specifying the template instantiation, the casts can be implicit. **However,** do note that this is a cast, so is susceptible to errors which [Potatoswatter's brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22346540/213525) isn't.