# How do I initialize literal to size_t in C?

Tags: c

I have the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346369/initialize-integer-literal-to-stdsize-t), except I'm writing C.

How can I initialize a literal number to have the type `size_t`?

Basically, I have a macro that amounts to this:

```
#define myprint(S) { printf("hello %zu", S); }
```

and I would like to use it like this:

```
myprint(0);
```

But I'm getting the message:

> format '%zu' expects argument of type 'size_t', but argument has type 'int'

I've tried writing `0lu`, but it does not work for all architectures.

Comment: There is no literal suffix for this. Use a cast: `(size_t) foo`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's what I feared. Perhaps you could add your comment as an answer?

Comment: You should also put parentheses around that macro parameter in the expansion.

Comment: Safer version: `#define myprint(S) ( (void)_Generic((S), int: 0, size_t: 0), printf("hello %zu", (size_t)(S)) ) `

Comment: safest version `void myprit(const size_t size) { ... }`

Comment: @P__J__: Making it external rather than static inline, and gratuitous qualifier on arg, aren't the best ideas, but indeed using a function (ideally static inline) rather than a macro for this is the right thing to do.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE why it is not the best idea? Because you think so? But you are wrong. Inlining or not inlining, static or not static depends on the use. Why const:

Comment: @P__J__: Because (1) static inline is closer to OP's original intent with the macro; an external function has different linking semantics, and (2) the body is inherently so small (just wrapping another function call) that inline will not be any larger.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE leave for the compiler. BTW inline function does not have to be inlined unless you force the the compiler to do so. You did not answer why it is bad to be const correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no suffix specific to `size_t`.  You'll need to use a cast instead.

```
#define myprint(S) { printf("hello %zu", (size_t)S); }
```

Given how this is used, it's the best way to do it anyway.