# Do primitive types have also constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, primitive-types, built-in-types

I have read in Dr. Bjarne Stroustrup Book "The C++ Programming Language" 3rd edition that built in types have also constructors in C++ in section 10.4.2.

But then the following link says that POD types can't have constructors:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pod-types.html

Which is true? Do primitive types have also constructors in C++?

Comment: Please quote the relevant text from the book.

Comment: Indeed, without that we cannot clarify the situation. Although, reading that linked text, **POD != primitive**.

Comment: You can pretend they have constructors for most syntax.

Comment: You can safely assume Mr. Stroustrup is more reliable about C++ than a random website.

Comment: By the way, a POD class type must have a trivial default constructor per §9 [class]/6 and /10.

Comment: @Isaac, That FAQ is a recognized C++ resource. In fact, it and Bjarne's own FAQ were mostly combined to make the [official C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq) (or the closest to official we can have). Anyway, the FAQ should really say no user-defined constructors, but when it was written, there was no way to define a trivial constructor, so I guess it should say that it needs the implicit compiler-generated constructors.

Comment: @chris: Interesting. So it's not _just a random_ website. I guess **custom constructors** is what this FAQ actually meant. The primitive  types already have a constructor.

Comment: @aruisdante: OK. The link is about POD types and it says they cannot have a constructor hence they are usable in C too. The OP is asking whether primitive types have constructor or not. The bottom-line is the primitive types in C++ does have constructor, but PODs don't have.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors

Comment: @Isaac well, they do have them, they just must be automatically generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Isaac, POD types (including the built-in types) are not required to have one, but POD-class types are, but not a user-defined one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Bjarne means is that you can write `int(56)` or even `int()` to construct an integer. What the links means is that a **struct/class** is only a POD if it does not have a constructor declared. So Bjarne talks about primitive non-struct types and the link talks about structs/classes so the two sources can coexist without contradicting each other.

Here is part of the definition from the link:

> a POD type's non-static data members must be public and can be of any of these types

Of course, this can only hold for structs. An `int` has no "data members". So although the link never mentions it directly, it only refers to structs and classes.

Comment: A POD also must have no methods (not just no declared constructor/destructor). Basically, you can only do what is allowed with a C struct if you want the struct to be portable between C++ and C without modification.

Comment: @aruisdante, Not true. Only virtual functions are prohibited. FWIW, I'm talking about C++11, but the C++03 text is *A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct,
non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator
and no user-defined destructor*, where *An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).*

Comment: @chris You're right, I had read it as making a struct that would compile with both, but it just meas a struct that acts like a C-struct for initialization/copy, not that would be compilable as such.