# Constructors for Primitive data types

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Is

```
int i(10);
```

the same as

```
int i = 10 ;
```

what are the differences in both the methods?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors

Comment: Neither is a "constructor". Only class types have constructors. Your question is about the grammar of *initialization*.

Comment: So primitive types don't have constructors ?

Comment: The difference is in the syntax, both do the same. IIRC generally declaration + assignment in a single statement actually invokes the copy constructor, whereas the first case will invoke a constructor that takes an `int` parameter, but I am not sure how this applies to primitive types, since I am not aware of their implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the standard (§8.5/14):

> The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally
>   insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity
>   being initialized has a class type; see below.

So in your case, there is no difference (the "see below" refers to the differentiation between copy-initialization and direct-initialization, but as we are talking about `int`, this is not of interest here).

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences between those two:

```
/*1*/ int a(10);
/*2*/ int a = 10;
```

is that the first one **cannot** be used as an in-class member initializer:

```
struct A
{
    int a(10); // compilation error
};
```

whereas the second one **can** be:

```
struct A
{
    int a = 10;
};
```

As well as in any other places, where *brace-or-equal-initializer* (defined below) in required.

```
brace-or-equal-initializer:
    = initializer-clause
    braced-init-list

braced-init-list:
    { initializer-list ,opt }
    { }
```

*Reference:*

> #### § 9.2 Class members `[class.mem]`
>
> 4. A *brace-or-equal-initializer* shall appear only in the declaration of a data member. (For static data members, see 9.4.2; for non-static data members, see 12.6.2).

which means that alternatively the below can be used instead:

```
struct A
{
    int a{10};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same.

```
int i = 10 // initializes memory  and loads with value 10.

int i(10) // does the same just writing style is different.It is like initializing a class of int.
```

Answer (score -3):

int i(10);:- this deceleration is a wrong way to declare a method. to declare the method we need to a return type for the method, method name, and the argument list that is used inside the method. int i(10) is a  wrong method deceleration.

int i=10:- means that i is a int type variable that has 10 value. both are different in there meanings

to initialize the variable from constructor we use like that

```
class I {
int i;
i(int i) {
this.i=i;
}
psvm(string []m){
I i= new I(10);
}
 }
```

Comment: In C++ a declaration with initialization as ```int i(10);``` indeed is possible.