# What is "int();"?

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, built-in-types

What is this:

```
int();
```

? Is it a call to a default `int` constructor? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors) built-in types don't have constructors. Then what is it? I know (more or less) what it does - it returns an int equal to 0:

```
int a = int();   // after this a == 0
```

And it looks like a default constructor. So why can't this:

```
int a;   // local variable
```

also initialize `a` with 0? I'm trying to understand how built-in types work and when they get initialized with `0`, and when they don't.

Comment: Because in C++ the philosophy is you don't pay for what you don't need. So, you'd use `int a;` if you don't need `a` to be initialized at that point, and `int a = int();` if you want it initialized.

Comment: According to your citation the built in types *do* have constructors, unless you're prepared to believe anecdote over the language standard and the author of the language.

Comment: keep in mind that "int a;" on its own will only reserve the memory slot, and the value will be whatever was previously in that reserved memory spot.  Providing a value intializer will ensure it starts with a default value for that type.  I prefer C++11 standard initilizer { }.

Comment: @chris, had to connect a mouse to my tablet for the delete icon to show - requires hover