# C++11 Generic Function for initializer_lists Averages

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

I have a exercise in *C++ Primer 6th*:

> Complete the program by supplying the `average_list()` function. It should be a
>   template function, with the type parameter being used to specify the kind of
>   `initialized_list` template to be used as the function parameter and also to give the function return type.

I have no idea with it

Here is part of a short program:

```
int main() {
     using namespace std;
     // list of double deduced from list contents
     auto q = average_list({15.4, 10.7, 9.0});
     cout << q << endl;
     // list of int deduced from list contents
     cout << average_list({20, 30, 19, 17, 45, 38} ) << endl;
     // forced list of double
     auto ad = average_list<double>({'A', 70, 65.33});
     cout << ad << endl;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you come across?

Comment: I have problem with list, I have no idea with parameter passed in template :(

Comment: @M.Daniel the type is `std::initializer_list<T>` does that help?

Comment: As a hint, your function signature might look like `template <typename T> T average_list (std::initializer_list<T>);`.

Comment: Usually the exercise portion in a book comes after the portion which explains concepts needed for those exercises. If you read it, you should already know how to do this exercise.

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow. Take your time to first read which kind of questions are to be asked here and we'll be glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go with something like this:

```
#include <iterator>                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
auto average_list(const std::initializer_list<T> &&v) -> decltype(T() / 1.0)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), T()) / static_cast<float>(std::distance(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
}
```

The line

```
auto average_list(const std::initializer_list<T> &&v) -> decltype(T() / 1.0)
```

Says that `average_list` takes an initializer list const reference to some type `T`, and returns the type obtained by dividing a `T` by a float.

The function's body simply uses STL functions from `numeric` and such.

Comment: You don't need to take `std::initializer_list` by `const&`.

Comment: @Simple Thanks, I see your point. I like doing this if only as "documentation" for myself that there's only an intent to go over and not modify. Again, you have a point.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But why using T()? What does this mean?

Comment: @M.Daniel See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors) for the meaning of `int()`, e.g.. I've often seen the convention that, consequently, numeric-like types should have a default constructor that initializes to something like 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a *parametrized function* that uses a *template* which makes the type of the variable a parameter.

The type of the passed values then can be deduced by the compiler which *specializes* your function to handle the type that was passed.

Judging by the name `average_list()`, the function should return the average value of the arguments passed, thus you need to write the code to make that, starting from a one type, for example `int` and then simply replace `int` with a *template parameter*. The syntax to do this is:

```
template <typename T> // prefix in front of the function
```

Example: the function below handles only `int`

```
int sum_vector(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    int sum = 0;      

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i){
       // accumulate sum
       sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

to make the type of the above function parameter, you could write:

```
template<typename T> T sum_vector(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    T sum = 0;      

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i){
        // accumulate sum
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

then `T` is determined depending on the type of the `vector` passed as an argument, i.e. if the type of the vector is `int`, every `T` *"becomes"*<sup>1</sup> an `int`, if `double` then every `T` *"becomes"* a `double`.

---

<sup>1. The compiler gets you a function instantiation with type `int`.</sup>