# What does i(row) and j(col) mean?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Okay so I'm trying to understand what the int i(row) and the j(col) means in this set of code, does it set i to the value in row?

```
for( int i(row); i < row + height; ++i )
{
    // Cycle through cols
    for( int j(col); j < col + width; ++j )
    {
        // Change the value at position ( i, j ) to the fillChar
        board[i][j] = fillChar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, think of it as calling the "constructor" of `int`.

Comment: @brian so i = row ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `int` also has a default constructor: `int i{}; // i is 0`.

Comment: so could I just write int i = row instead? @BrianRodriguez

Comment: Yes you could.  I would say that would improve the readability of the code.

Comment: @Brian Intrinsic types don't have constructor functions.

Comment: @user0042 That's why I was careful to say "think of it as a constructor".

Answer (score 1):

non-`class`/`struct` types in C++ (such the intrinsic/"primitive" types `int`, `long`, etc) [do not have constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors), but they do have an initialization syntax which looks the same as a constructor call.

As an example, calling a class-type's constructor looks like this:

```
my_class myClassInstance( myClassConstructorArgument );
```

Similarly, using `int`'s initializer looks like this:

```
int myInt( myInitialValue );
```

So in your case, `for( int i(row); ...` is the same as `for( int i = row; ...`.

[There is a third syntax that uses curly braces too](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

```
int x = 1;
int y(2);
int z{3};

cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
```

gives the output `1 2 3`.