# Difference between (double) and double()

Tags: c++, casting

I think this question is not new, but I can not find an answer anywhere.

Is there a difference between `(double)myInt` and `double(myInt)` in c++?

Comment: No difference in effect.  The former is a C-style cast, and is in general disfavor.  The latter is a constructor-style cast, and is in general disfavor as well.  The generally advocated way is to use a static cast, `static_cast<double>(myInt)`

Comment: Though it's okay in this case, but please bless others by using `static_cast` instead. Always.

Comment: As the answers say, `double(myInt)` and `(double)myInt` mean the same thing. But with `long double` they're not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(double)myInt` is [type conversion](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) from `int` to `double`. In modern C++, it is **strongly** advised to use `static_cast<double>(myInt)`.

`double(myInt)` calls `double`'s "constructor" which also does the type conversion.

Essentially, they are the same and will result in the same ASM output.

Check the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 5;

    double b(a);           // line 1
    double c = (double)a;  // line 2

    return 0;
}
```

Both lines result with the same ASM:

```
cvtsi2sd        xmm0, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-24], xmm0
```

Check [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+5%3B%0A%0A++++double+b(a)%3B%0A++++double+c+%3D+(double)a%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:41,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:41,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:72.53765932792584,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:27.46234067207416,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Compiler Explorer is a nice tool thank you for your link. Are you sure, that `double(myInt)` calls a constructor. I always thought that constructors only exists for classes. And in c++ double is not a class is it?

Comment: @NelDav built-in types like `double` don't have constructors but this type of [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) reminds on constructor. Check another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113429/5517378)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a difference between (double)myInt and double(myInt) in c++?

Only difference is syntactical. The meaning is the same.

The latter "functional" syntax cannot be used with compound types: `int*(x)` does not work.