# What is pointer() in unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, unique-ptr, default-constructor

I read now unique_ptr source code in libstdc++.

```
 public:
   typedef _Tp*               pointer;
   typedef _Tp                element_type;      
   typedef _Tp_Deleter        deleter_type;

   // Constructors.
   unique_ptr()
   : _M_t(pointer(), deleter_type())
   { static_assert(!std::is_pointer<deleter_type>::value,
           "constructed with null function pointer deleter"); }
```

I don´t understand.Does "pointer()" call constructor? but "pointer" is an alias for type _Tp*

Comment: It calls the default constructor of `_Tp*`, which has almost no effect, except constructing a `nullptr`.

Comment: clearly, primitive fundamental types support the same default construction syntax as classes. But is there any advantage to the compiler (or other) over just writing `nullptr`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression

```
pointer()
```

zero-initializes the data member `pointer` of the class that has a pointer type. For pointer types it means setting a pointer to a null pointer.

From the C++ 14 Standard (8.5 Initializers)

> 11 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
> (), shall be value-initialized

and

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:

> (8.4) — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Further

> 6 To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> (6.1) — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the
> value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;104

and in the footnote 104 there is written

> 104. As specified in 4.10, converting an integer literal whose value
>      is 0 to a pointer type results in a null pointer value

Answer (score 5):

For all types, `T()` is an expression that [*value-initialises*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) an unnamed instance of that type. For non-class, non-array types, value-initialisation is [*zero-initialisation*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

> the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to `T`

And for a pointer type, that's a null pointer