# Code that compiles in C++ but has no obvious meaning. Function call operator applied to a simple type such as char

Tags: c++, clion

This compiles in C++

```
    if (char()=='a') {

    }
```

I discovered this after opening a very old project in CLion (Yeah Jetbrains!).  The code in question was trying to do this:

```
    if (ProfileType()==GI_PROFILE_TYPE && forEdit && 
        !user.AccessGranted(AK_GI_MOD))
        return false;
```

with the assumption that ProfileType() was a member method to return the type of a profile.  But it wasn't.  It was this:

```
typedef char            ProfileType;
```

It should have been

```
GetType()
```

This code has silently compiled for years (decades?) and never actually worked properly.  I only found this because I noticed that CLion gave the warning that the condition was always false.  At first I doubted the warning, and then I doubted the navigate-to, and then I realized the warning was actually correct!  I've run several static analysis tools on this code over the years and nothing ever caught this mistake till now.  I build with gcc -Wall and it didn't complain about this either...

My question is:  what does this actually mean:

```
char()
```

Comment: These are analogous to default c'tors (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113365/1424875 and links from there)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: So that condition is basically an `if (false)`. No wonder it never worked.

Comment: This question does demonstrate why caution is needed with using type aliases for basic types like `char` - such things have their place, but also their pitfalls (which is true of features of any programming language).   I'd say the bigger problem in the code-base the OP is working with is the fact that it appears some developer *assumed without checking* that `ProfileType` was the name of a (member) function rather than a type alias.   I'd suggest a high chance of other hidden flaws as well - such things are rarely one-offs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax for the default constructor, e.g.

```
auto x = MyClass();
```

Will call the default constructor of MyClass.
For primitive types like `char`, it zero initializes them, e.g.

```
char() == 0
```

Comment: Thank you!.  Once again I'm reminded about how horrible c/c++ is as a language.  And I used to think I was actually competent at at!

Comment: That's because C/C++ isn't a language.  C and C++ are distinct languages; for example, C++ has inheritance and C doesn't.

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with the syntax `char()` to get a zero-initialised `char` - it is well specified and consistent part of C++, and (arguably) preferable over the `(char)0` that is part of C to get the same effect.   This question doesn't demonstrate a typical usage of the syntax though.